# SQL: compare two table record by record

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, fetch

I want to compare two tables recordby record. I have two cursor for each table. The code looks like this

```
Declare Cursor c1 for SELECT * from Table1
OPEN c1
While @@Fetch_status=0
Begin
  Declare Cursor c2 for SELECT * from Table2
  OPEN c2
  WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0
  Begin
     /*Comparison happens here*/
  END
END
```

When fecthing, must I specify which cursor I am fetching and how do I do that?

**EDIT**

For each record in Table1 I want to

- Search Table2 for that record based on the primary key.
- When it is found, I want to update the extra column values in Table2 based on the value of a column in table1.
- When this record is missing in table2, I want to copy it
  from table1 to table2 and set a default value of the extra column in
  table2.

Open to other solutions (not restricted to cursors)

Comment: Why don't you write the query as a join?

Comment: you should provide the information which db system you are talking about.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do you mean? How do I do that?

Comment: @wkaha how do I do that?

Comment: Can you choose between ms sql, mysql, oracle, db2, ..... ?

Comment: is it a mysql, pgsql, oracle or a mssql system?

Comment: Can you detailed explain this phrase "compare two tables recordby record"?

Comment: Sorry but when we have a SQL question where the asker brings up in comments `How do I do a JOIN?` then it's probably not an appropriate Q for the site.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I want to perform an action on the record if it is present and so something else on it if it is not. I want to do that in the shortest time also. I know the join can be set to return either records found in both or records found in 1 and not the other. That is why I was wondering if it will be appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @jpo perhaps if you tell us all that you're hoping to accomplish then we can help you with a good solution. otherwise we're going to just flail around tilting at windmills and taking SWAGs and only getting the information that we need after each failed/unsatisfactory attempt.

Comment: @jpo . . . I think you should ask another question, giving more information about what you are trying to do in the code blocks and how you are identifying if a row is present in both tables.

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13767575/807223

Comment: I think it's better to edit this one (as you did). The other question will be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If tables have same column definition, the fastes way is just use 'except' clause:

```
SELECT * from Table1
except
SELECT * from Table2
```

also run it in opposite way:

```
SELECT * from Table2
except
SELECT * from Table1
```

You'll see the exact set difference:

**[EXCEPT and INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

**[Redgate has a great tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)** for this, if you'd rather just spend a few dollars:

You can get a free trial to see if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just...

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON <your matching criteria>
```

...and then perform INSERT for the rows whose right "half" is NULL and UPDATE for those whose isn't?