# comparetwo SQL table record by record

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, fetch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: compare two table record by record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766946/sql-compare-two-table-record-by-record)

I want to compare two tables recordby record. I have two cursor for each table. The code looks like this

```
Declare Cursor c1 for SELECT * from Table1
OPEN c1
While @@Fetch_status=0
Begin
  Declare Cursor c2 for SELECT * from Table2
  OPEN c2
  WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0
  Begin
     /*Comparison happens here*/
  END
END
```

When fecthing, must I specify which cursor I am fetching and how do I do that?

This is what I want to do:

For each record in Table1 I want to

- Search Table2 for that record based on the primary key.
- When it is found, I want to update the extra column values in Table2 based on the value of a column in table1.
- When this record is missing in table2, I want to copy it
  from table1 to table2 and set a default value of the extra column in
  table2.

Comment: If you are using SQL-SERVER 2008 or above, try to look at [**`MERGE`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). It may be helpful for your case.

Comment: @jpo . . . You do not need cursors for this at all, so you shouldn't assume they are necessary.  What you are looking for is the `MERGE` statement.  Start with the documentation for that.